# Yii query caching with infinite expire time

Tags: php, caching, yii, query-cache

I'm using query caching with infinite expire time. Consider a piece of code below for example:

```
$channels  = Channels::model()->cache(0)->findAll(array('order' => 'channel_name'));
```

This statement is supposed to make in entry in the cache and it is doing, but it is not fetching the data from cache, rather it is directly going to DB for the result.

While, if I provide a expire time > 0 (zero), then it works smoothly. For example:

```
    $channels  = Channels::model()->cache(20)->findAll(array('order' => 'channel_name'));
```

works perfectly for 20 seconds and fetch the results from cache.

We are confirmed about it as we enabled the log and saw the profiling.

Infinite expire time works also fine for caching key/value pair using `Yii::app()->cache->set()` or `Yii::app()->cache->get()`

Any idea if im doing anything wrong ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs `0` means that cache is disabled.

Just set it to some large value. If you need it in many places define it as a constant to avoid confusion of [magic number antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), ie:

```
define('IMMUTABLE_CACHE', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 100);

$channels  = Channels::model()->cache(IMMUTABLE_CACHE);
```

Comment: please help me find where it says '0' is to disable caching. Also, enabling log it clearly says that cache is being prepared. In my case, Im using Sqlite and I can clearly see 'INSERT' command with '0' expire time.

Comment: In [active record class docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#cache-detail). This is not same as `cache` component.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have got it.